# Using "My Inbox" web part in SharePoint 2013

Tags: outlook, exchange

How can I use the "My Inbox" (Outlook) web parts in SharePoint 2013? According to [this thread on MSDN](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/cea510bc-c53e-4995-ae7b-00fd3ad6fa9d/) the web parts are available, but only for sites created with the SharePoint 2010 experience or sites migrated from 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

Site Setting
Web Design Galleries > Web parts
Files
New Document> New
Select: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.OWAInboxPart"

Comment: Sorry folks,
i'm just not finding these options in my SharePoint 2013, Site Setting **Web Design Galleries** > Web parts Files New Document> New Select: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.OWAInboxPart" What section should Web design galleries appear under in site settings?